# Loading remote application would it lead to App Store rejection?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova, jqtouch

I have an application using JQtouch and would like it to be on the App Store.

Will my application get rejected from the App Store if all the functionality is done remotely (loading in UIWebView) and I provide no offline functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had apps approved in the app store that were just a web view pointed on a JQTouch application. However, I loaded the .html from a local file included in the app. I believe the no "web clippings" clause of section 12.3 in the App Approval guidelines is only meant for clippings of full web sites. Embedding a mobile web application in a local app will likely get accepted.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Apple App Approval Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 12.3: Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected.

Basically if your app does not add anything to the experience of viewing the website, then you may get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be a problem.  Apple reviewers are probably the most fickle people on the planet, but I can think of several apps that are UIWebView based, and which provide little or no offline functionality.